# How do I set the name of the stored procedure in the database using StoredProcedure after creating

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc, pojo

How do I set the name of the stored procedure in the database using StoredProcedure after creating.

I don't want to use the Constructor for the Spring JDBC StoredProcedure Object that I have to pass in the datasource and the name.

protected StoredProcedure(DataSource ds, String name)
ds - DataSource to use throughout the lifetime of this object to obtain connections

name - name of the stored procedure in the database

This is due to trying to use POJO.  So I want to use the  Constructor without them and then call setDataSource on the StoredProcedure but how do I then set the name?

hmm please hel[p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StoredProcedure is designed for extension but if you do want to set it you can use

```
RdbmsOperation.setSql(String name)
```

RdbmsOperation is higher up the type hierarchy of StoredProcedure.

Essentially all the StoredProcedure's constructor does is call that method with the string passed in.